# All my projects are gone from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I was deleting old projects from my Android Studio when it suddenly froze, I tried closing it, but it wouldn't close.
I waited for some time and after a bit Android Studio became normal.
But when I tried opening my other projects, I noticed that all of my projects were [gone.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlbDA.png)
I tried to see if they were present in the Directory under AndroidStudioProjects, but they were not.
It's all gone.
Can someone help me, please?
My Operating System is Linux.

Comment: Navigate to that folder manually, and see if ur projects are there

Comment: project will be thr in the directory i think your recent list is just cleared and remember save your project to other partition

Comment: @Shank Arif Nouman Khan
No they are not present there, that is why im really worried, all my hardwork is gone. [See this.]:(http://imgur.com/WRYJze3)

Comment: @NikhilPandita I recommend you try to do a recovery, However, I am not familiar with Linux, I suggest you connect your hard drive to windows computer and Install Recuva and do a Deep scan on that directory **AndroidStudioProjects**. Or give TestDisk a shot (Linux)

Comment: Also the more you use ur computer the lower the chances are to recover